# Изменения классов и стилей при скроллинге

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, html5

Есть хедер и контент, при скроллинге хедер становится фиксированным, а контент нужно сдвинуть вниз на высоту хедера. Пытался сделать [по примеру](https://learn.javascript.ru/onscroll) - там в песочнице все получалось, скопировал, вставил, изменил переменные - не работает, пишет ошибку в `getBoundingClientRect()`. Вот мой упрощённый код:

```js
var header = $('#header');
var heightHeader = header.outerHeight(true);

window.onscroll = function() {
  if (window.pageYOffset == 0) {
    $('#header').css({
      left: 0,
      right: 0,
      top: 0,
      position: 'relative'
    });
    $('#content').css({
      "margin-top": "0"
    });
  } else {
    $('#header').css({
      left: 0,
      right: 0,
      top: 0,
      position: 'fixed'
    })
    $('#content').css({
      "margin-top": heightHeader + "px"
    });
  }
};
```

```css
#header {
  height: 300px;
  background: #bbb;
}

#content {
  height: 900px;
  background: #444;
}

.fixed {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="header"></div>
<div id="content"></div>
```

Все сделал, всем спасибо!))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
var header = $('#header');
var heightHeader = header.height;


window.onscroll = function() {
  if (window.pageYOffset == 0) {
    $('#header').css({
      left: 0,
      right: 0,
      top: 0,
      position: 'relative'
    });
    $('#content').css({
      "margin-top": "0"
    });
  } else {
    $('#header').css({
      left: 0,
      right: 0,
      top: 0,
      position: 'fixed'
    })
    $('#content').css({
      "margin-top": parseInt($('#header').css('height')) + 100
    });
  }
};
```

```css
#header {
  height: 300px;
  background: #bbb;
}

#content {
  height: 900px;
  background: #444;
  color: #fff;
}

.fixed {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="header">header</div>
<div id="content">content</div>
```